# Explain OpenSSL Debug Messages

Tags: debugging, openssl

I ran an openssl server with:

`openssl s_server -accept 2000 -cert ~/sss/server.crt -key ~/sss/server.key -debug`

I ran an openssl client with:

`openssl s_client -connect localhost:2000`

Then, from the client, I sent over the text 'hello'.

The server responded with:

```
read from 0x7fc359415ed0 [0x7fc35980fe03] (5 bytes => 5 (0x5))
0000 - 17 03 01                                          ...
0005 -
read from 0x7fc359415ed0 [0x7fc35980fe08] (32 bytes => 32 (0x20))
0000 - 0a d1 ab 77 96 cd af 46-a0 26 11 f5 34 3b 77 39   ...w...F.&..4;w9
0010 - 8f 44 26 f7 f5 87 46 74-22 5f 27 34 f1 61 7f cb   .D&...Ft"_'4.a..
read from 0x7fc359415ed0 [0x7fc35980fe03] (5 bytes => 5 (0x5))
0000 - 17 03 01                                          ...
0005 - 
read from 0x7fc359415ed0 [0x7fc35980fe08] (32 bytes => 32 (0x20))
0000 - e3 14 00 18 82 95 d9 aa-9a 70 7e 75 b2 21 26 91   .........p~u.!&.
0010 - eb fe 3d ac 9e 24 73 08-39 9b cd ab d0 99 cc 71   ..=..$s.9......q
```

**What do each of the memory addresses refer to? 0x7fc359415ed0, etc.**

Comment: interesting, is this regarding heartbleed?

Comment: hi yes. i'm trying to figure out the memory content of the server and figure out what content is leaked during heartbleed exploit.